# Как определить, что MediaPlayer остановлен? (Android) [Закрыт]

Tags: mediaplayer, android

Как определить, что MediaPlayer остановлен?
Пробовал код:

```
    public void lmm() {
    if (mmp.isPlaying()) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else {mmp.start();}
    ...
    }
```

Пробовал ещё в этом же коде перед mmp.isPlaying поставить "!", но результат такой же: не получается. Пожалуйста, помогите! <br>
**Решил проблему вот так:**

```
  if (mmp.isPlaying()) {
                //do nothing
            }
            else {
                mmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mainmenu);
                mmp.setLooping(true);
                mmp.start();
            }
            ...
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

что конкретно происходит? аудио проигрывается или нет?
Вы метод prepare() вызывали? дело в том что если создать плеер методом player=new MediaPlayer() и задать аудио дорожку методом player.setDataSource(path) то просто необходимо вызвать метод prepare(). однако если вы создаёте методом create(context, uri)  то prepare вызывать не нужно.

Comment: Плеер создаю вот так:
mmp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.mainmenu);
  mmp.setLooping(true);
  mmp.start();

Comment: и что выдаёт isPlaying() ? true или false ?? аудио проигрывается хоть ?

Comment: В том то и дело, я не знаю как получить этот true/false. Аудио проигрывалось, потом определённый метод останавливает плеер, а эта функция должна проверить, работает ли плеер или нет, и если нет, ть надо запустить плеер сначала.

Comment: так всё-таки что выдаёт  isPlaying() ? в консоль выведите его. Log.e() или как хотите.
я не представляю как этот метод может врать. он просто обязан работать без сбоев :)

Comment: isPlaying в начале выполнения программы выдает true.
Но когда надо снова запустить плеер, то ничего не получается!

Comment: т.е. looping был false ? изза этого она не хотела воспроизводить аудио заново ?